# Compiling GoodbyeDPI v0.1.6

Tags: makefile

I fail to compile sources of GoodbyeDPI v0.1.6 project https://github.com/ValdikSS/GoodbyeDPI/releases/tag/0.1.6.
When I run the command

```
make CPREFIX=x86_64-w64-mingw32- BIT64=1 WINDIVERTHEADERS="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\WinDivert-2.2.0-Source\WinDivert-2.2.0\include" WINDIVERTLIBS="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\WinDivert-2.2.0-A\WinDivert-2.2.0-A\x64"
```

which uses dependency on WinDivert project https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html I get the following output:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres goodbyedpi-rc.rc goodbyedpi-rc.o
process_begin: CreateProcess<NULL, x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres goodbyedpi-rc.rc goodbyedpi-rc.o, ...> failed.
make <e-2>: Can't find the file specified.
make: *** [manifest] Error 2
```

although I write the make command as it's said in Readme (at least I think so). I'm not very experienced in make procedure, so help me to figure out the problem, please.

Comment: Do you have `x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres` installed?

Comment: Is there any way to get it for gnuwin32 or I should download mingw?

Comment: MSYS2 provides `windres`, but it's not prefixed with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-`. Haven't heard of gnuwin32, but maybe it does this too. Then you'll need to somehow tell the makefile to use `windres` instead of `x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres`.